# OPNsense + HAProxy behind NAT

Tags: haproxy, nat, opnsense

I am new to OPNsense/HAProxy and struggling for more than 3 days to make it works but unfortunately nothing achieved.

So in short words trying to achieve this kind of logic:

Dedicated Server (Proxmox VE/1 Public IP) -> (NAT) OPNsense + HAProxy -> Other VMs connected to OPNsense LAN interface.

#### The configuration of **Proxmox Server** is as the following:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet static
        address 94.130.x.x/26
        gateway 94.130..x.x

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 10.10.10.1/24
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0

        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o enp0s31f6 -j MASQUERADE
        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o enp0s31f6 -j MASQUERADE
        post-up   iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1
        post-down iptables -t raw -D PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
        address 172.16.0.1/24
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
```

Ok, so created new VM(OPNsense), install and configure it as following:

- WAN -> vtnet0 (bridge to vmbr0 at Proxmox Server)
- LAN -> vtnet1 (brigde to vmbr1 at Proxmox Server)
- WAN configured with `10.10.10.10/24`
- LAN configured with `172.16.0.1/24`
- DHCP server on LAN, `172.16.0.2-172.16.0.254`

> Now the servers part:

- VM 1

VM #1(Ubuntu Server) with OpenLiteSpeed Web Server running `example.com` and Postfix/Dovecot for email purposes, and connected to vmbr1 (LAN of OPNsense connected to Proxmox vtnet1)
The Ubuntu server gets IP successfully via OPNsense DHCP (IP `172.16.0.2`, Gateway `172.16.0.1`).

VM #2 VM(Ubuntu Server) with OpenLiteSpeed Web Server running anotherexample.com and Postfix/Dovecot for email purposes and connected to vmbr1 (LAN of OPNsense connected to Proxmox vtnet1)
The Ubuntu server get the IP successfully via OPNsense DHCP (IP `172.16.0.3`, Gateway `172.16.0.1`).

Both of the VMs connected through OPNsense LAN and able to communicate with public internet successfuly.

> CloudFlare DNS for example.com:

```
A Record example.com pointing to Public IP of Proxmox Server ->
94.130.x.x
```

Created some iptables rules to communicate from Public IP to local OPNsense and HAProxy:

**For OPNsense:**

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 10443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.10:10443
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.10.10:443
```

#### HAProxy configuration:

```
#
# Automatically generated configuration.
# Do not edit this file manually.
#

global
    uid                         80
    gid                         80
    chroot                      /var/haproxy
    daemon
    stats                       socket /var/run/haproxy.socket group proxy mode 775 level admin
    nbthread                    1
    hard-stop-after             60s
    no strict-limits
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param   2048
    spread-checks               2
    tune.bufsize                16384
    tune.lua.maxmem             0
    log                         /var/run/log local0 info
    lua-prepend-path            /tmp/haproxy/lua/?.lua

defaults
    log     global
    option redispatch -1
    timeout client 30s
    timeout connect 30s
    timeout server 30s
    retries 3
    default-server init-addr last,libc

# autogenerated entries for ACLs


# autogenerated entries for config in backends/frontends

# autogenerated entries for stats




# Frontend: Public_Facing_Pool ()
frontend Public_Facing_Pool
    bind *:443 name *:443  proto h2 
    bind *:80 name *:80  proto h2 
    mode http
    option http-keep-alive
    maxconn 500

    # logging options
    # ACL: Web-Server
    acl acl_65baf2832edf80.37086579 hdr_beg(host) -i example.com

    # ACL: Web-Server1
    acl acl_66baf2832edf80.37086579 hdr_beg(host) -i anotherexample.com

    # ACTION: Web-Server
    use_backend Web-Server if acl_65baf2832edf80.37086579

    # ACTION: Web-Server
    use_backend Web-Server1 if acl_66baf2832edf80.37086579

# Backend: Web-Server ()
backend Web-Server
    # health checking is DISABLED
    mode http
    balance roundrobin

    http-reuse safe
    server Web-Server 172.16.0.2:443 

# Backend: Web-Server1 ()
backend Web-Server
    # health checking is DISABLED
    mode http
    balance roundrobin

    http-reuse safe
    server Web-Server 172.16.0.3:443 

# Backend: acme_challenge_backend (Added by ACME Client plugin)
backend acme_challenge_backend
    # health checking is DISABLED
    mode http
    balance source
    # stickiness
    stick-table type ip size 50k expire 30m  
    stick on src
    http-reuse safe
    server acme_challenge_host 127.0.0.1:43580
```

## statistics are DISABLED

```
Trying to open in browser `example.com` or `anotherexample.com` it fails to open.

What am I missing?
```

Comment: How far do packets make it? Have you attempted a capture on opnsense?

Comment: @vidarlo I mean, the packet go through as i see from OPNsense firewall logs that it is accepting the connection e.g. port 443 from public -> to 443 OPnsense -> to HAProxy, but can't figure it out what is going wrong...